# iOS apps unresponsive after reboot

Tags: iphone, ios, performance

I have an iPhone 11 Pro running iOS 13.5.1, but this issue has happened since at least iOS 11 (with an iPhone X)

If I either turn off or reset the device, when it reboots, the first app or two that I open will start out okay for a few seconds but will then freeze. If there is a scrolling list, it will stop scrolling. I can't tap on anything until I force quit the app via the multitasking UI and relaunch it.

Has anyone else observed this issue?